# I've managed to completely bork my network connection in 18.04

Tags: wireless, ethernet, 18.04

Essentially this:

Since I've done the upgrade to 18.04, I get these problems.

1. Wifi connects/disconnects, mostly shows a ? no bars etc like I would expect. Although sometimes it does.
2. Wired just basically refuses to connect, declares itself as un-managed.

Is there a handy way I can "start again" with setting up networking? I think that's the most obvious way to fix this.

Additional info from ifconfig:
eth0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        ether d4:3d:7e:4a:11:9e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 250  bytes 65850 (65.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 28  bytes 3709 (3.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 31  base 0x9000

lo: flags=73  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3959  bytes 406686 (406.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3959  bytes 406686 (406.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s5: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.14  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::a266:2594:4e53:324b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 00:16:b6:58:6a:2a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3152  bytes 2130369 (2.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3702  bytes 456293 (456.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Comment: Go to  /etc/Network Manager/NetworkManager.conf
                a) change managed =false to managed=true
Go to    /etc/network/interfaces
                a) Make sure the following lines are there with nothing else:
                       auto lo
                       iface lo inet loopback

Comment: Thanks, in part, I have wifi back. It's now down to wired, which just won't activate a connection.

Comment: If it helps, the ethernet card is: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller driver: r8168. I am thinking maybe the driver is not the right one.

Comment: Looking at dmesg all I see is page faults. Namely 

dmesg | grep r816
[74324.723019] r8168 0000:01:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0002 address=0x0000000000000080 flags=0x0020]